# Неправильное склонение слова "подписчик"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

При наведении курсора на метку - показывается количество подписчиков, в таком формате - `20 подписчиков`. При другом количестве подписчиков, например, когда их 61 - все равно пишется `61 подписчиков`, хотя должно быть - `61 подписчик`. То есть, либо неправильно работает метод определения изменения окончания слова подписчик, либо метод не работает вообще. Что бы было понятнее, наведите на тег - objective-c, и Вы увидите те самые `61 подписчиков`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Алгоритм уже реализован, просто был неверный перевод.

**Оригинал:**

> $FollowerTotal$ followers

**Переводы:**

Developer note: VARIANT: one ([Tx:4197](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266045?key=0eeaf527a8ec47de141996614a35e544|many)), исправил:

> <s>подписчиков</s> подписчик

Developer note: VARIANT: few ([Tx:5816](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266045?key=0eeaf527a8ec47de141996614a35e544|many)):

> подписчика

Developer note: VARIANT: many ([Tx:5817](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40266045?key=0eeaf527a8ec47de141996614a35e544|many)):

> подписчиков

Изменения появятся на сайте при следующей сборке проекта. Это происходит регулярно, за точным расписанием можно обращаться к [@Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky)

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать алгоритм определения окончания существительного, в зависимости от того, какое число рядом с этим словом стоит. Писал такой алгоритм правда на objective-c, который довольно понятно читается. Надеюсь он сможет помочь.

```
 + (NSString *)changeStringWithCount:(NSInteger)count {

    if ((count % 100 >= 11) && (count % 100 <= 19)){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld подписчиков",(long)count];

    }else {
        if (count % 10 == 1) {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %ld подписчик",(long)count];

        }else if (count % 10 == 2 ||
                  count % 10 == 3 ||
                  count % 10 == 4) {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %ld подписчика",(long)count];

        } else {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld подписчиков",(long)count];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что касается алгоритма расчета: можно оптимизировать и считать `count % 10` и `count % 100` один раз.

Comment: @NickVolynkin объясните, не понял

Comment: @NickVolynkin я понял, спасибо, но это незначительно оптимизирует его, в нынешних условиях, этого будет просто не заметно